# Directory is not accessible: the file or directory is corrupted and unreadable

Tags: data-recovery, storage, file-corruption, filesystem-corruption

I have studied [this post](https://superuser.com/q/1554727/571029) and [that one](https://superuser.com/q/241817/571029) which are about a whole device being corrupt. But in my case, only a single directory is corrupt:

[image: Error screenshot]

I'm using [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to scan/repair the specific directory. It is still in progress:

[image: TestDisk scanning]

Did anybody run into the issue for a single directory?

### Update

Eventually, Windows 10 got stuck in this page while booting:

[image]

Comment: Yes, sometimes it means that sector on the drive has gone bad, which recovery will be very difficult, I have always used Spinrite for this type of sector recovery, not free just the best.

Comment: @Moab Thanks! I'm going to try [SpinRite](https://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm), if there is a trial ...

Comment: Unfortunately no trial since it is written for DOS, there is no way for him to protect its trial use. If spinrite cannot recover the data, everything else is a waste of time.